# Change text color of md-toolbar header and icon

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I need to change the  Text and icon color to white.

I tried the below css which is the same given in the angular material toolbar page (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar) is not working.

```
.toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar md-icon.md-default-theme {
  color: white; }
```

Then I added this css and it changed the color of  heading:

```
.toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar h2 {
  color: white; }
```

Here is the codepen i tried: http://codepen.io/nhere/pen/RadGQL

But I need to change the entire toolbar text color to white. How to do this ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for because the text color is already set to white. Which toolbar in the code pen are you talking about?

Comment: That not the pure white color. `toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar h2` by using this I change the heading text color to white. But still icons are not in pure white color. There is a little color change.

Comment: What is the definition of a pure white color? That is the white color that is default by the browser. If you want a different white color then just change `color:white;` to something else. Maybe take a look at this and choose a color to your liking: http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Comment: Can you please try to remove this CSS `toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar h2` from codepen and see the color change.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML of your codepen. It shows:

```
<md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg" style="color: greenyellow;"></md-icon>
```

Change `greenyellow` to `white`. Watch out for the inline CSS in the HTML. Also note that in the case that the icons aren't captured by the classes you have referenced in your CSS. Give the icons their own ID and change the coloring (using `!important` if need be to override anything in the Material default stylesheets).

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar use primary color of your theme. You can define your color themes:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Or overwrite with css:

```
md-toolbar.md-default-theme:not(.md-menu-toolbar), md-toolbar:not(.md-menu-toolbar) {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a lighter font color (not white) rather than black, customise your primary palette but add the following attribute:

```
'contrastDefaultColor':'light'
```

Here's an example:

```
var customPrimary = {
  '50': '#ffffff',
  '100': '#87b065',
  '200': '#7aa755',
  '300': '#6e964c',
  '400': '#618544',
  '500': '#55743b',
  '600': '#496332',
  '700': '#3c522a',
  '800': '#304121',
  '900': '#233019',
  'A100': '#a1c286',
  'A200': '#afca97',
  'A400': '#bcd3a8',
  'A700': '#171f10',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
 };
 $mdThemingProvider
    .definePalette('customPrimary',
     customPrimary);

 $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
   .primaryPalette('customPrimary');
```

This will show a dark(ish) green toolbar with a lighter font-color. If you remove **contrastDefaultColor** option, then the font-color will be black